# Linq xml query with arguments

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

My goal is to create a query, for an XDocument, that only returns the `strikePrice`'s value if the correct **date** is located in the attribute `symbol`.

The `symbol`, in the example XDocument, has a ticker `AAPL`, **date** `131221`, type `C` and it ends with a variable number of digits.

Example XDocument:

```
<query>
    <results>
        <optionsChain>
            <option symbol="AAPL131221C00245000" type="C">    
                <strikePrice>245</strikePrice>
                <lastPrice>299.04</lastPrice>
                <change>0</change>
                <changeDir/>
                <bid>314.1</bid>
                <ask>317</ask>
                <vol>1</vol>
                <openInt>5</openInt>
            <option/>
        <optionChain/>
        <optionsChain>
        ....
        <optionsChain/>
    <results/>
<query/>
```

I can retrieve the **date** from the `symbol`'s string with the following code:

```
string startingString = "AAPL";
string symbol = "AAPL131221C0024500";

string date = symbol.Substring(startingString.Length, 6))
```

I can retrieve **ALL** the strikes with the following query:

```
XDocument Doc = Example XDocument;
List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list = Doc.Descendants("results")
                .Descendants("optionsChain")
                .Descendants("option")
                .Elements("strikePrice")
                .Select(d => d.Value)
                .ToList();
```

How can I combine the two and build a query that **ONLY** returns `strikePrice` values if the correct **date** is located in the attribute `symbol`?

Comment: By "Correct Date" do you mean a hard coded value to search for?

Comment: Yes, I will have a string variable that will include the desired date.

Comment: I can currently get all the dates and all the strikePrice's.  But now I want to get all the strikes after I choose a specific date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using XPath instead and querying the values that way.

```
var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//query/results/optionsChain/option[starts-with(@symbol, '--lookup value--')]/StrikePrice");
```

Haven't tested the above but is useful for XmlDocument.

Here is an example of using this with XPathEvaluate on an XDocument http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675197.aspx

Comment: What return type is that?

Comment: It will give you a collection of nodes that you can iterate over. Not at a development machine, but if you do var value =, you should be able to see

Comment: I get: System.Xml.Linq.XDocument does not contain a definition for SelectNodes.

Comment: Im using 'XDocument', not 'XmlDocument'.  Can I convert it?

Comment: Updated my answer with an XDocument example

Comment: Using the example, Im geting an error: The name 'query' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: No, I have 'var query = (IEnumerable)xmlFile.XPathEvaluate("//query/results/optionsChain/option[starts-with(@symbol, '--lookup value--')]/StrikePrice");' but now I cant do anything with the var?

Comment: declare the variable in the correct scope and that should fix it. You're trying to use 'query' outside of its scope